# How to get the second element from the last in Julia

Tags: arrays, vector, julia

Is there any way to do this in Julia?

```
#Python
lst = [1, 2, 3]
print(lst[-2]) # prints out 2
```

I know `last` function gets the last one, but I want to get the second one from the last.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Within the context of array indexing, `end` can be used as a special syntax to represent the last index of the array, whatever that may be. So `lst[end-1]` is what you're looking for.

```
julia> lst = [1, 2, 3];

julia> lst[end-1]
2
```

You might want to check out the Python section of Julia's ["Noteworthy Differences from Other Languages"](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/noteworthy-differences/#Noteworthy-differences-from-Python) page. A few of the relevant notes from that page:

> - Julia does not support negative indices. In particular, the last element of a list or array is indexed with `end` in Julia, not `-1` as in Python.
> - Julia requires end for indexing until the last element. `x[1:]` in Python is equivalent to `x[2:end]` in Julia.